# Example of evaluation of $\int_0^1\left(\sum_{k=0}^n (f(x))^k\right)^{\alpha}dx$, for some choice of $f(x)$ satisfying certain requirements

Tags: real-analysis, integration, examples

Let $0<\alpha\leq\frac{1}{2}$ a fixed real number. I wondered if it is possible to evaluate the sequence of definite integrals $$\int_0^1\left(\sum_{k=0}^n (f(x))^k\right)^{\alpha}dx\tag{1}$$
for some example of a continuous function and positive $f(x)>0$ for all $0<x<1$, and $f(x)\neq\text{constant}$.

> **Question.** Do you know an example of evaluation of $(1)$, the evaluation $\forall n\geq 1$, for a choice of $0<\alpha\leq\frac{1}{2}$ and a function $f(x)$ satisfying previous requirements? **Many thanks.**

If the example that I evoke is in the literature, please refer it and I try to search and read the example from the literature.

Comment: Please explain what "evaluate" means.

Comment: I think that if it is possible to get an expression for each $n\geq 1$ in terms of well-known constants and/or in terms of particular values of elementary/special functions. The real $\alpha$ is a choice in your example. Many thanks for your attention @MaxAlekseyev

Comment: All, if the only option is to use the definition of Riemann integral (or other) to get such definite integral, that is you cann't show an explicit example of evaluation of the sequence of previous definite integrals, explain if it is possible that one can to find such example that I evoke, or if it is impossible to get those definite integrals for any example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you allow for special functions, you of course allow for quite some beasts. Generally, your expression is
$$
I = \int_{0}^{1} dx \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n} (f(x))^k \right)^{\alpha }
= \int_{0}^{1} dx \left( \frac{1-(f(x))^{n+1} }{1-f(x)} \right)^{\alpha }
$$
Let's choose $f(x)=x^2 $ and $\alpha =1/2$, and substitute integration variable $x=\sin t$. This yields
$$
I = \int_{0}^{\pi /2} dt \sqrt{1-\sin^{2n+2} t} \\
=\frac{\pi }{2}\cdot {}_{n+2}F_{n+1}
\left( -\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2n+2},\frac{3}{2n+2},\ldots,\frac{2n+1}{2n+2};\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{2}{n+1},\ldots,\frac{n}{n+1},1;1 \right)
$$

Comment: Choosing $f(x)=x$ and substituting $x=\sin^2 t$ yields something similar (roughly speaking, swap the first and second sequences in the argument of the hypergeometric function, while shifting the odd sequence in the numerator up by 2).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.